# Working in a group blender project

Tags: workflow

Me and my team are new to blender, we are now planning for a small project. What I want to ask here are some questions regarding the team work:

- We use git for version control in web projects, Is there any special version control for blender project.
- Creating object of each file and integrating in the project is one way we saw to complete the project. But is there any good way to work in the group?

Please tell us from your experience what might be the best way to work together in a group blender project.

Answer (score 12):

### Version control for blender

There is no special version control system for blender. Your three main choices are git, Mercurial, and SVN.

While I have used git for blender projects and it works ([here](https://github.com/VScalia/RadishZombies) is a game that was created in a group and was version controlled in git) it is not the best suited because git does not handle binary files, think images and blend files. There is an [addon](https://github.com/ldo/blendgit) that integrates git in to blender, and let you see and save versions of your file.

SVN is svn and you need a server set up to run that. (The Blender institute has used SVN for their open movie projects).

Mercurial (while I personally have not used it) is best suite to use for Blender. It has the simplicity of git, and (somehow) it can diff binary files.

CG cookie has a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4Lt7mYN5k8) about setting up version control for blender.

### Project Structure

[File linking](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html) in blender is a pain, but it is the only way to work together in a group.

Say you have one main file, then you will link in the assets that are all separate files. Being separate files enables each person to work on a different piece of the whole at the same time.

Comment: @MrZak I know about the addon. but that does not help the huge problems with the linked library system. Try linking in a object, then renaming it, or restructuring the file system...

Comment: I wanted to say it may help to edit libs, but of course that doesn't mean it really will.

Comment: I travelled through SO since I was also looking for a VCS for Blender. We are a small developer studio and use Perforce for binary files. It has its hickups. I found [Snowtrack](http://snowtrack.io/) and [Alienbrain](https://alienbrain.com/). I haven't tried either of them, but they both look interesting.